# How to extract distribution of r.v. $X$ from probability generating function of $X$?

Tags: distributions, function

How to extract distribution of r.v. $X$ from probability generating function of $X$?

The p.g.f. of $X$ is:

$$G_X(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}t^kP_X(k).$$

That is, if $G_X(t)$ is known, then (how) can one "figure out" $P_X(k)$?

Comment: Since the values are right in front of you--the probabilities are, by definition, $P_X(k)$ for each $k$--please explain what you mean by "extract."  That might depend on *how* $G_X$ is "known," so perhaps you could say a little more about that, too.

Comment: The values are, but what about the domain? Since the p.g.f. is usually given in e.g. a piece-wise definition. Is the domain the same as the integers that $k$ gets?

Comment: That, too, is explicitly in front of you in the summation notation.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the usual extraction procedure from Taylor series:

$$P_X(k)=\frac{1}{k!}\left.\frac{d^k}{dt^k}G_X(t)\right|_{t=0}$$

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as 'low quality', probably because it is so short. Can you add some text to explicate this?

Comment: Maybe there should be a moderator override button to remove 'low quality' designation from high quality short answers which are flagged due to being too short.

Comment: @Mark What we (and other active people such as Gung) currently do when automatic flags (or even user-driven flags) look inappropriate is to weigh in with an appropriate comment intended to dissuade people from acting automatically on the flag.  That tends to work.